# limit Listview in yii2 without pagination

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Listview in yii2 to display items, in this case the items are video thumbnails, and i want to display only 5, i tried to limit the query...

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Video::find()
            ->select(['video.*', 'COUNT(video_like.video_id) AS countlike'])
            ->joinWith(['likes'])
            ->groupBy(['video_like.video_id','video.video_id'])
            ->limit(5)
            ->orderBy(['countlike' => SORT_DESC])
    ]);
```

but it doesnt work...
my listview is:

```
<?php echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'pager' => [
    'class' => \yii\bootstrap4\LinkPager::class,
],
'itemView' => '_video_item',
'layout' => '<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">{items}</div>{pager}',
'itemOptions' => [
    'tag' => false,
],
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-pagination#$pageSize-detail).

This should work for you:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
         'query' => Video::find()
            ->select(['video.*', 'COUNT(video_like.video_id) AS countlike'])
            ->joinWith(['likes'])
            ->groupBy(['video_like.video_id','video.video_id'])
            ->orderBy(['countlike' => SORT_DESC]),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 5,
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks!! it works, i only have to add a comma at the end of '->orderBy(['countlike' => SORT_DESC])'

Comment: Fixed, and Happy hacking ;)